# Export Csv from large data using mysqli in chunks method

Tags: csv, mysqli, export-to-csv, chunks

How can I export CSV from a large database?
I have faced time out error.

I have more than 1GB data in my table.
If I try to create CSV using a custom method, server through the timeout error.

Answer (score -1):

If you have more data in your table and you want to export in csv , then you have faced exception / Time execution error.

I have got a better solution mentioned below and also fully tested.
Please use and enjoy.

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
set_time_limit(0);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "demo");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$limit = '';
$sql ="SELECT * from user";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
$fileName = 'report.csv';
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
$rounds='';
if($row_cnt>0){
    $processAtOnce = 10;
    if($row_cnt>$processAtOnce){
        $rounds = round($row_cnt / $processAtOnce);
    }else{
        $rounds = 1;
        $processAtOnce = $row_cnt;
    }   
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rounds; ++$i) {  
        $limit = $processAtOnce;
        $offset = $i * $processAtOnce;
        $sql1= $sql .' limit '.$offset. ','.$limit;
        $result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);       
          while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }

    }
    unset($result1);
    unset($result);
}
```

## ---------- Database ----------

```
CREATE TABLE `newdemo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `roll` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `newdemo`
--
  ALTER TABLE `newdemo`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `newdemo`
--
ALTER TABLE `newdemo`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```